# Max sizeof metafunction in variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a metafunction(?) in variadic templates to calculate the max of `sizeof` of a few types at compile-time.

```
template<typename... Ts> struct MaxSizeof {
  static constexpr size_t value = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct MaxSizeof {
  static constexpr size_t value = std::max(sizeof(T), typename MaxSizeof<Ts...>::value);
};
```

But I'm getting a few strange errors:

```
MaxSizeof.h(7): error C3855: 'MaxSizeof': template parameter 'Ts' is incompatible with the declaration
MaxSizeof.h(7): error C2977: 'MaxSizeof': too many template arguments
MaxSizeof.h(5): note: see declaration of 'MaxSizeof'
```

Could you help fixing my code?

The compiler is MSVC++2017 toolset v141.

Comment: Are you missing a **static** before constexpr?

Comment: @Phil1970, thanks, I've updated the code and the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specialization has not correct syntax, it should be:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct MaxSizeof<T, Ts...> { // Note the <T, Ts...> here
    // ....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::max` is only marked `constexpr` since C++14, so you will have to write your own. Also, you can't overload structs, which is one reason why your code fails.

Here's a solution requiring C++14's `std::max`, which you can change to use a custom one as required.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct MaxSizeof : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::max({sizeof(Ts)...})> {};
```

Comment: But here http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/ in the first example under "Varidic data structures" the author seems to overload a struct, doesn't he?

Comment: @SergeRogatch If you mean the very first, that's a function. There is a later one with structs, and that is partial specialization.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 fixes needed:

1. As pointed out by @Phil1970 , I forgot `static` for `value` definition.
2. I had to specify template arguments on line 7: `struct MaxSizeof<T, Ts...> {` instead of simply `struct MaxSizeof {`.

So the following code compiles:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct MaxSizeof {
  static constexpr size_t value = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct MaxSizeof<T, Ts...> {
  static constexpr size_t value = std::max(sizeof(T), typename MaxSizeof<Ts...>::value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

another minor fix needed:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct MaxSizeof<T, Ts...> {
  static constexpr size_t value = std::max(sizeof(T), MaxSizeof<Ts...>::value); // there should be with no `typename` 
};
```